# Поймал две щуки или двух щук?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, числительные

Мой друг поймал ***две щуки*** и ***три леща***. Правильно?

Или *двух щук* и *трех лещей?*

Answer (score 5):

(1) ***Мой друг поймал двух щук и трех лещей.***

(2) ***Мой друг поймал две щуки и три леща.***

*Поймал двух щук и трёх лещей* — это, конечно, правильно. Вот и Розенталь нам говорит об этом:     В различии форм ***поймал трех рыбок – съел три рыбки*** сказывается то обстоятельство, что во втором случае имеется в виду кушанье, т.е. неодушевленность. http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_08

Да, съесть трех одушевленных рыбок было бы неверно. А вот если рыбки уже пойманы, то они  не такие уж одушевленные, если только  не золотые и не говорящие. **Поэтому хотелось бы дать оценку и второму варианту.**

Вот примеры из Нацкорпуса:

**Поймал две рыбки,** обязательно и третью Бог пошлет. Нашел два боровичка на полянке ― не уходи! [Евгений Весник. Дарю, что помню (1997)]

В течение следующего часа мне удается **поймать еще три рыбки** той же неизвестной породы, а Дмитрию Павловичу ― ни одной.  [Олег Зайончковский. Счастье возможно: роман нашего времени (2008)]

И что же, править будем?

**Обратимся вновь к Розенталю, вот его полный текст.**

1. Некоторые существительные склоняются **по типу одушевленных и неодушевленных**, например: изучать живые существа – изучать живых существ, рассматривать бактерии – рассматривать бактерий, уничтожать микробы – уничтожать микробов... Первые формы употребляются **в общелитературном языке, вторые связаны с более архаическим или профессиональным употреблением.**
2. В различии форм **поймал трех рыбок – съел три рыбки** сказывается то обстоятельство, что во втором случае имеется в виду кушанье, т.е. неодушевленность (ср.: съесть кильки, сардины, шпроты – как нерасчлененный продукт; но: съесть карасей, раков, цыплят – как единичные предметы). Возможные варианты: есть креветок, устриц – есть креветки, устрицы, пулярки.
3. В вариантах ***купить двух коров – купить две коровы, подстрелить трех уток – подстрелить три утки*** (при названиях животных в форме женского рода, когда речь идет об общем счете, купле-продаже) **вторая форма имеет разговорный характер**.

Нет, Розенталь не дает однозначного ответа и **не рекомендует Р.п. для любой живности** при любых обстоятельствах, даже род различает. А выражение ***уничтожать микробов*** вообще считает архаичным или профессиональным.

А **в Грамматике-80** можно прочитать, что  допускаются такие варианты: ***поймал три птички –  поймал трех птичек.***

**И тогда делаем вывод:** в разговорной речи вариант "Мой друг поймал две щуки и три леща"  вполне допустим.

Comment: Как всегда вы даете профессиональный ответ! Всегда приятно читать ваши ответы.

Comment: Спасибо, спасибо, Серж! И не забывайте, пожалуйста, что очень многим участникам приятно ВАС видеть на форуме как можно чаще.

Comment: Sharon, спасибо. В последнее время никак не могу найти время, чтобы отвечать на вопросы. С т/ф тяжело.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, правильно *"поймал дв**ух** щук и тр**ёх** лещ**ей**.*

С людьми и **животными** (одушевлёнными существительными) в винительном падеже сочетаются формы числительных *двух, трёх, четырёх.* Они совпадают с формой родительного падежа для них.

Кроме того, есть распространённое выражение *"убить дв**ух** зайц**ев**"* (не "два зайца").

Можете проверить ещё в Нацкорпусе: *[поймал двух щук](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%20%D1%89%D1%83%D0%BA)* (один пример против ни одного на "две щуки"), *[убил двух тетеревов](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2)* (так же).